# Create a session variable when user clicks a button inside a loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I have a button inside a loop.
When the user clicks on the button I want to create a $_SESSION variable with the value of a variable inside the loop.
For example, the variable $id_puja is 767 at this loop item, when the user clicks on the button I want to create the session variable $_SESSION['clicked_puja'] = $row['id_puja'].

This is the button:

```
while{...
$id_puja = $row['id_puja'];
...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
...
}
```

I
EDITED, full loop code:

```
<?php
$resultadopujas=0;
global $mysqli;
$loop = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tb_pujas
    WHERE subasta_puja = '".$subasta."'")
or die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
$orden = 0;
$resultado = $loop ->num_rows;

if ($resultado == 0){

    ?>  <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">


                    <p><?php echo $resultado."NO HAY PUJAS"?></p> 


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
$numpuja=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loop))
    {$numpuja = $numpuja+1;
        $originalDate = $row['datetime_puja'];
        $newDate = date("d-m-Y H:i:s",strtotime($originalDate))
        ?>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: white">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <img  style="width: 80px;height: auto;align-self: " src="garantia.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <img  style="width: 80px;height: auto;align-self: " src="ok.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <img  style="width: 80px;height: auto;align-self: " src="extra.png">
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <p><strong>Dia/Hora puja: </strong><?php echo $newDate?></p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <p><strong>Precio puja: </strong><?php echo $row['precio_puja']." €"?></p> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">

                        <p><?php echo "<strong>Puja núm:</strong> ".$numpuja?></p> 
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12">

                        <p><?php echo "<strong>Comentarios:</strong> ".$row['comentarios_puja']?></p> 
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <img  style="width: 100%;height: auto;align-self: " src="https://cribbeo.com/pujas/<?php echo $row['foto1']?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <img  style="width: 100%;height: auto;align-self: " src="https://cribbeo.com/pujas/<?php echo $row['foto2']?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <img  style="width: 100%;height: auto;align-self: " src="https://cribbeo.com/pujas/<?php echo $row['foto3']?>">
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">


                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <script>
                            function myclick(){
                                alert (<?php echo $row['precio_puja']?>);
                            }
                        </script>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" id="boton" onclick="myclick()" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

                    </div>


                </div>







            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <?php

}

?>
```

EDITED modal part

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">



    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>




                <h4 class="modal-title">Mensajes de la subasta <?php echo $referencia."VAR=".$_COOKIE['puja']?></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#486A86; color: white">
                <div class="container">
                    <header class="header">
                        <h1>Chat</h1>
                    </header>
                    <main>
                        <img  src="images/logohorizontal.png" alt="Cribbeo" width="200px">
                        <div class="userSettings">
                            <label for="userName">Usuario: <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']?></label>
                            <input id="userName" type="hidden" placeholder="Username" maxlength="32" value=" <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="chat">
                            <div id="chatOutput"></div>
                            <input id="chatInput" type="text" style="background-color:white; color: #486A86" placeholder="Escribe aquí el texto de tu mensaje" maxlength="128">
                            <button id="chatSend" style="background-color:#486A86; color: white">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is chat.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chatInterval = 250; //refresh interval in ms
    var $userName = $("#userName");
    var $chatOutput = $("#chatOutput");
    var $chatInput = $("#chatInput");
    var $chatSend = $("#chatSend");

    function sendMessage() {
        var userNameString = $userName.val();
        var chatInputString = $chatInput.val();

        $.get("./write.php", {
            username: userNameString,
            text: chatInputString
        });

        $userName.val("");
        retrieveMessages();
    }

    function retrieveMessages() {
        $.get("./read.php", function(data) {
            $chatOutput.html(data); //Paste content into chat output
        });
    }

    $chatSend.click(function() {
        sendMessage();
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        retrieveMessages();
    }, chatInterval);
});
```

Comment: You can achieve this with help of Ajax.

Comment: @Shivrudra, As test I have created an onclick function, but I always get the value from the last item in the loop, not from the selected item

Comment: @IncredibleHat, I have include the code with the loop, the button is at the bottom inside the loop

Comment: *"I want to create the session variable `$_SESSION['clicked_puja'] = $row['id_puja']`."* - That should work. Where did you try that? Assigning the session array to the looped row's id and then putting that back in where you want it should work. What difficulty are you having doing this?

Comment: Thanks for adding that @mvasco it really sheds light on your issue. Also, showing a huge problem you have introduced as well with a **looped redefine of a javascript function**. This needs a bit of work to get going differently :( Also this would all be mounds easier with the jquery lib ;)

Comment: I also can't see where `$subasta` is assigned in the `WHERE` clause. Does this have anything to do with all this? If so, then assign the session array to that, no?

Comment: sir can you started session in a page ?

Comment: Couple more notes: `global $mysqli;` is needless where you have it. Remove it. Also you are open to sql injection attacks with that SQL query. So when you get this issue resolved, please do look into [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: It seems you want to create session only when the click happens. You need to get the appropriate value from the source send it via ajax and create the session.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, the loop is working fine, currently there are 4 objects. $subasta is declared previously.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what I need is to store as session variable the $row['id_puja'] value from the object where the user clicks on the button, I have trie with an onclick function, but the $row['id_puja'] value shown when clicking on the button is always from the last item in the loop not from the selected one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
//START OF LOOP... 

//Add data-var attribute to your button to store the value of the session variable to be picked up by jQuery.
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg session-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-var="<?php echo $id_puja;?>">Open Modal</button>

//END OF LOOP..

// jQuery CDN link
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
  $('.session-btn').on('click', function(){
  var session_var = $(this).data('var');
  console.log(session_var);  // prints the session variable value to the console.
  $(document).ready(checkModal);

  function checkModal() {
    if($('#myModal').is(':visible')){ 
      //if the modal is visible on the page

      $.ajax({
        url: 'read.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {session_var: session_var},
        success: function(){
          alert('success');
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

**In read.php file**

```
<?php 
  require("connect.php"); 
  session_start(): 

  //connect to db 
  $db = new mysqli($db_host,$db_user, $db_password, $db_name); 
  if ($db->connect_errno) { 
    //if the connection to the db failed 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error; 
  } 

  if(isset($_POST['session_var'])){ 
    $_SESSION['session_var'] = $_POST['session_var'];
    echo $_SESSION['session_var'];

    $query="SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id_puja ='".$_SESSION['session_var']."' ORDER BY id ASC"; 
    //execute query 
    if ($db->real_query($query)) { 
      //If the query was successful 
      $res = $db->use_result(); 

      while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $username=$row["username"]; 
        $text=$row["text"]; 
        $time=date('G:i', strtotime($row["time"])); //outputs date as # #Hour#:#Minute# 

        echo "<p>$time | $username: $text</p>\n"; 
      } 
    }else{ 
      //If the query was NOT successful 
      echo "An error occured"; 
      echo $db->errno; 
    } 
  } else {
    echo 'variable is not posted!';
  }
  $db->close(); 
?>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176968/discussion-between-ujjwal-verma-and-mvasco).